# Getting Error while performing distributing Load testing

Tags: jmeter, load

I am doing Distributing Load testing by j meter but when i run the test case from remote host then it shows 100% error. My system is running as a master and the remote system or the slave system which is connected properly and run their threads too but with 100 % error. It gives me 100% error in both the cases. How to handle it to test load and performance testing on the API. Suggest some answers to get progress.

I tested my apis on different conditions but still facing same issue.

Comment: first look at the log for error(s) and edit your question with the error(s)

Comment: Echoing the statement above, what are the errors expressed in your error  log?  I might also ask whether you  have any  delays in your test code whatsoever to  account for the natural delays as  part of any  client-server  conversation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure both master and slave are running the same Java version. If they are different - download and install the [appropriate one](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre8-downloads-2133154.html)
2. Make sure both master and slave running the same JMeter version. If they are different - download and install the latest [JMeter version](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)
3. Make sure both master and slave have the same extensions and/or plugins installed as if you have test plan which relies on a plugin which is not present on the slave - the execution will fail. Use [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) to synchronize extensions or alternatively just copy over master JMeter instance to the slave machine
4. If your test relies on external data (CSV files, property files, files used for uploading, etc.) - make sure to copy them to the slave as well.
5. In case of any problems check `jmeter-server.log` file on the slave machine for any suspicious entries
6. Just in case check out the following material:

   - [Remote Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
   - [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)
   - [JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf)